# Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Azure AAD add group member

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I followed azure documentation and created following request to add member to AD group using powershell script. But getting error Bad request.

```
    $clientId = "d4b2ca57-yyyy-yyyy-zzzz-50a4ca126390"
$clientSecret = "nnr7Q~zzzzz"
$tenantID = "4f6eyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-0981d022yyyy"


$ReqTokenBody = @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_Id     = $clientId
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret
}
$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/domain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody

$TokenResponse
$token = $TokenResponse.access_token
$token
$Headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $token"}
$Headers
#Get group List -> working fine
$AadGroupListRequestParams = @{
    Method  = 'GET'
    Uri     = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups'
    Headers = @{
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $token" 
    }
}
$AadGroupRequestzzz = Invoke-RestMethod @AadGroupListRequestParams
$AadGroupRequestzzz.value

#Add member to group -> not working
$AadGroupMemberAddRequestParams = @{
    Method  = 'POST'
    Uri     = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/fb30b950-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-6015f411ec3c/members/$ref'
    Headers = @{
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $token" 
    }
    Body = @{
     '@odata.id' = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/673cf709-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-c5c476d6yyyy"
}
}
```

#Tried passing below param separately , still no use
$params = @{
"@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/673cf709-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-c5c476d6yyyy"
}

```
$AadGroupAddMemberRequest = Invoke-RestMethod @AadGroupMemberAddRequestParams -ContentType "application/json" -Verbose
$AadGroupAddMemberRequest.value
```

Error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: The `group-id` in the URL needs to be replaced with the actual group id of the target group (eg. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/f4b9b4dd-50ad-4a25-8aa3-01c2a4fddb09/members/$ref`), and the `user-id` in the object reference in the body needs to be replaced with the actual user id of the user you want to add as a member (eg. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/cb455bba-1dd2-49a4-b53f-f0458d444620`)

Comment: @sindhu shree : also Please check if group already has that member. method may return a '400 Bad Request' response code when the object is already a member of the group.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have used right group id and user ID in the request, still getting the error.

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT Thanks for letting me know , Let me check on that.

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT Tried adding user who doesn't exists in the group, still the same.

Comment: updated question with full script. Kindly check and let me know what is missing. Listing group names api is working fine.

Comment: @sindhu shree : You may check if your token has correct api permission mentioned .see [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). decode your token in https://jwt.io, for application permission, check the roles claim if contains `Group.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, and for delegate permission, check the scp claim if contains `Group.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`. If not ..please add those permissions and grant admin consent.  Also try placing content type in headers.

Comment: Also try making token as secure string  `$token= "<token response that we get>"| ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force`

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT I have given all access , both delegated and Application. Am able to get the group properties and also able to list all groups name so that means token is fine right?

Answer (score 0):

The request body needs to be in JSON format, as you are passing the parameter **ContentType** as `application/json`

[Add members - Request Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body)

> In the request body, supply a JSON representation of a directoryObject, user, group, or organizational contact object to be added.

Use `ConvertTo-Json` on the body

```
Body = @{
     '@odata.id' = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/673cf709-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-c5c476d6yyyy"
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: I tried, still giving me same error

Comment: @sindhushree I can confirm that I've taken your code as-is, only replaced the necessary variables while including the JSON conversion, and it's successful for me. Have you tried manually adding the user into the group? Note that the group cannot be mail-enabled. If it's a M365 group, it must be a standard user object as well. There's a few restrictions as noted in the API link I shared. Have you also tried the `New-MgGroupMemberByRef` cmdlet?

Comment: It is security group, not mail enabled one. And it is AD synced group, is that an issue?
I haven't tried with New-MgGroupMemberByRef

Comment: @sindhushree Groups synced from on-prem AD can't be managed from AAD (or using MS Graph), so that's why it's not working. You need to update the group from on-prem, and then sync it to AAD.